# Android design patterns, Singletons per-object class in Realm for composition?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, design-patterns, realm

I'm designing an android app in realm that graphically charts data, using a very straight forward object class representation:

```
@RealmClass
public class Graph implements RealmModel {
  @PrimaryKey
  private String UUID;
  public RealmList<DataSet> dataSets;
}

@RealmClass
  public class DataSet implements RealmModel {
  @PrimaryKey
  private String UUID;
  public RealmList<DataPoint> dataPoints;
}

@RealmClass
  public class DataPoint implements RealmModel {
  private String UUID;
}

 Basically Graph.Contains DataSets.Contains DataPoints
```

I'd like to run realm in it's own thread, separate from the UI. I'm considering using the Singleton design pattern to manage all 3 levels of data. There could be 1 singleton per-realm-model, 3 singletons in total, or there can be one master singleton.

In both cases, the singletons will have the traditional sup'd up List methods available from RealmModel,

```
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction(){
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm){
            realm.copyToRealm(graph);
        }
    });
```

along with other methods I create:

```
public void bulkAdd() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm){
            for(int i=0; i<100;i++){
                //doStuff();
...      });
```

Before/After that operation I want to use the Factory Pattern to manage the details of creating and configuring each of the RealmModels. So my question is, should I create 3 singletons, an instance for each RealmModel, 1 master singleton that manages all RealmModels, or use another design pattern?

A side-note, non-priority is that I would also like to take advantage of async if possible, ie:

```
    private void asyncAddQuote() {
    ...
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> remoteItem = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {...
```

But I don't know which overall composition of design patterns are best for this application. I need to keep in mind that Realm transactions are limited to one thread. I need to drive UI elements like RecyclerView in the UI thread. In certain modes the application runs as a Service, so in service mode my realm needs to be on the service thread.

I've built the Graph singleton up to recyclerview level and I'm about to build the rest. I want to avoid gottchas when codding the compositional/control layer. I would appreciate your thoughts on design patterns and options for overall composition. Thanks!

Comment: Querying on a background thread and sending unmanaged results to the UI thread means you lose lazy evaluation of result sets. I hope you know that?

Comment: I don't know. When my application is in "service/record" mode, data writes to realm are a priority, as data flow rates are high (120hz). Charting the results during services/record mode will be done at a managed rate, at or in most cases below the data input rate. In "view" mode, my application will/should have the Charting and UI as a priority thread reading from Realm. How do you suggest I structure my threads for the two scenarios? I noticed realm now has built-in async transactions, I should updated my code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a Factory that produces different POJOs (Graph/DataSet & DataPoint) then use [async transaction](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#asynchronous-transactions) with bulk insert for inserting a batch of objects into Realm:

```java
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
                Graph graph = MyFactory.INSTANCE.getGraph();
                bgRealm.insert(graph);
            }
        });
```

you can also use an async transaction to query for objects added previously from the background thread:

```java
 RealmResults<Graph> graphs = realm.where(Graph.class).findAllAsync();
 graphs.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Graph>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChange(RealmResults<Graph> graphs) {
                        //update UI
                    }
                });
```

Please note: Don't put Realm itself inside a singleton, having a singleton means that regardless from where you access the data (in your case a Realm) it will return the same instance which is against the [threading model](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#using-a-realm-across-threads) of Realm. Realm instances are already thread confined (ThreadLocal) i.e it will return the same instance when accessed from the same thread.

Comment: `Realm instances are already thread confined (ThreadLocal) i.e it will return the same instance when accessed from the same thread.` Yes, but `getDefaultInstance()` is reference counted paired with `close()`

Comment: @Nabil, thanks for reply, which answers another question (partly) about where to put Realm. Currently I have it Activity level which hosts a fragment. I've seen it done at the Application level, do you recommend this? Given the requirements to make realm writes a priority on the service fragment, while still having the ability to drive UI elements, where should I put my realm instance for consistent access from the singleton and fragments? The service mode needs options to run in the background, hence it will probably extend Service in that mode.  Panda that makes perfect sense, thanks.